# How to convert a string to a constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How to convert the string `"User"` to `User`?

Comment: Are you trying to call a variable function?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question; however, are you trying to create a new constant based on a string, OR find an already initialized constant? Also are you looking for vanilla ruby or also Rails?

Answer (score 106):

```
Object.const_get("User")
```

No need to require ActiveSupport.

Comment: Usage example: 

`class User; def self.lookup; const_get('SomeClassName);end; end`
`User.lookup` will return class itself.

Answer (score 61):

You can use the `Module#const_get` method. Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> ARGV
=> []
irb(main):002:0> Kernel.const_get "ARGV"
=> []
```

Answer (score 38):

If you have ActiveSupport loaded (e.g. in Rails) you can use

```
"User".constantize
```

Answer (score 29):

The recommended way is to use ActiveSupport's constantize:

```
'User'.constantize
```

You can also use Kernel's `const_get`, but in Ruby < 2.0, it does not support namespaced constants, so something like this:

```
Kernel.const_get('Foobar::User')
```

will fail in Ruby < 2.0. So if you want a generic solution, you'd be wise to use the ActiveSupport approach:

```
def my_constantize(class_name)
  unless /\A(?:::)?([A-Z]\w*(?:::[A-Z]\w*)*)\z/ =~ class_name
    raise NameError, "#{class_name.inspect} is not a valid constant name!"
  end

  Object.module_eval("::#{$1}", __FILE__, __LINE__)
end
```

Comment: Since Ruby 2.0 has reached EOL, there is no longer any need to pull in ActiveSupport as a dependency to reference a constant with a string. :-)

Comment: See also `'User'.safe_constantize`

Comment: Recommended by whom?