# does ruby need a string to class method?

Tags: ruby

I have a ***set*** of classes with static methods. Example member of class set:

```
    class George

    def self.ugh()
            printf( "Hello world\n" )
    end # self.ugh()

    end # class george
```

I need to do the following, but I don't have what I need.

```
    p George.object_id
```

The code I'm working with passes the class name (aka var). I've found a
solution that seems ugly, but it works.

```
    var = "George" # What I have
    cmd  = "#{var}.object_id"
    p eval( cmd ) # right object_id
```

I would think there's a better way. Seems like ruby's missing a
s_to_class() method.

The only other ideas I've found, that don't work.

```
    klass = class << var; self; end
    p klass.object_id # wrong object_id

    klass = var.singleton_class()
    p klass.object_id # wrong object_id
```

Anyone know a better way to get a class object (aka receiver) from a
string/symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides a `constantize` method, if you've got that available. Otherwise, use `Module#const_get`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361347/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-constant-in-ruby) for more details.

Comment: Which also uses `eval` (`module_eval` actually) with some syntax checking first... +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks.

  klass = Object.const_get( var.intern )
  p klass.object_id # works!!!

Thanks I would have never noticed this trick... Since Dave Thomas' book only uses it to get the value of PI.

Comment: @eclectic923 Yeah - I guess you just need to remember that class identifiers are actually just constants. It's how it works, but we don't tend to think about them like that usually.

Comment: @eclectic923 Please accept answers that solve your problem. This encourages others to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `eval` usage to make it slightly less evil:

```
className = "George"
klass = eval(className)
klass.objectId
```

But more importantly, why are you passing around class names instead of passing around the classes themselves? Class "definitions" are just objects in Ruby, and you can pass them around the same way you can pass around any other kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that eval is the string to class method that you seek:

```
eval("George").object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A; end

id1 = A.object_id
id2 = Object.const_get("A").object_id

puts id1 == id2   #=> true
```