# How can I get a instance of a Class from a String in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a string to a constant in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361347/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-constant-in-ruby)

I am wondering whether there is a way for me to convert a string to a class in ruby. What i mean by this is that, given a String like

```
'Fixnum'
```

i want a way to get the class

```
Fixnum
```

back

can someone give me an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"FixNum".classify.contantize should do it

Comment: I think that's only in Rails. Anyway this question is (I hope) about to be closed as a duplicate...