# How can I extend an object in ruby with a module whose name is given in a parameter?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I would like to extend a Ruby object with a module, but I want to be able to change which module to use at runtime, and have the ability to vary this by object. In other words, I'd like to pass the name of the module to `extend` as a paramter. How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
module M1
end

module M2
end

class C
  def initialize module_to_use
    extend module_to_use
  end
end

m = get_module_name_from_config_file
c1 = C.new m
```

(Assuming that the method `get_module_name_from_config_file` returns a `String` with the desired module's name - here either `"M1"` or `"M2"`.)

But I get this:

```
error: wrong argument type String (expected Module).
```

because `m` is of type `String`, not `Module`, obviously. I tried it with `m` being a symbol too, but I get the same problem (replace `String` with `Symbol` in the error message).

So, can I convert `m` into something of type `Module`? Or is there another way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does something like this work with const_get ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361347/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-constant-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this (modified to use `const_get` per Jörg W Mittag's suggestion)

```
module M1
end

module M2
end

class C
  def initialize module_to_use
    extend module_to_use
  end
end

m = Module::const_get("M1")
c1 = C.new m
```

You had some errors in your code above, btw - `class` and `module` should be lowercase.

Comment: Please don't. There is absolutely no need to use `eval` here. Just use `const_get`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that works perfectly. I've corrected the capitalisation in the original question too.