# superclass mismatch: get class object (ruby)

Tags: ruby, exception, superclass

```
class A
end
class B
end
class Y < A
end
class Y < B # TypeError: superclass mismatch for Y
end
```

Is there a way to get the class the raises the superclass mismatch?
I would like to know that it is class `Y` that causes it and hold that class in my bare variables.

Comment: Do you use a script to generate those classes? Could you post the relevant parts of it?

Comment: These classes can be found in files that are dynamically loaded and may chnge over time. So a superclass mismatch can occur if the source changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A;end
class B;end
class Y < A;end
x = (class Y < B;end) rescue $!
p x.to_s #=> "superclass mismatch for class Y"
```

Now from this string `"superclass mismatch for class Y"`, you can get the class with:

```
Object.module_eval(x.to_s[/class (?<name>\S*)$/, 'name'], __FILE__, __LINE__)
#=> Y
```

(Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361347/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-constant-in-ruby#answer-2361652))

Comment: Continuing from @Priti's answer, you could get the class with `Object.module_eval(x.to_s[/class (?<name>\S*)$/, 'name'], __FILE__, __LINE__)`

Comment: @tessi please edit it on my answer. I am not strong on `Regex`, thus kept it blank. :)

Comment: @User no issue.. if you place it properly,you would get the result :)

Comment: I am working with maglev and named groups of regex do not work. Here is my code: https://github.com/knub/maglevrecord/blob/niccokunzmann/migration/lib/maglev_record/snapshot/snapshot.rb#L49 Note that it does not work for nested classes.. but this is no issue for me :)