# How do I dynamically constantize the name of a namespaced class?

Tags: ruby

Information on what's going on here in ruby: http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/constant-name-resolution-in-ruby/

Doesn't help me solve my problem.. but it at least explains they 'why'

---

I've written the following method:

```
# delegate to a user permission serializer specific to the given object
# - if a serializer is not found for the given object, check the superclass
#
# @raise [NameError] if none of object, or it's superclasses have a known
#   user permission serializer
# @return [UserPermission::*Serializer] returns serialized object
def self.serialized_for(object, user, klass: nil, recursion_limit: 5)
    object_class = klass ? klass : object.class
    # use demodulize to chop off the namespace and get the generic object name
    object_name = object_class.name.demodulize
    # bulid serializer name
    name = "::UserPermission::#{object_name}Serializer"

    begin
        binding.pry
        permissions = object.user_permissions(user)
        return name.constantize.new(permissions)
    rescue NameError => e
        raise e if recursion_limit < 1
        # try with super class
        UserPermission.serialized_for(
            object,
            user,
            klass: object_class.superclass,
            recursion_limit: recursion_limit - 1
        )
    end
end
```

The goal is to be able to retrieve the serializer of any subclass, provided the subclass has a superclass with a serializer already defined. (I'm using ActiveModelSerializers, but that's not important here).

My problem is that I'm receiving a non-namespaced class when `name.constantize` runs.

My existing classes:

- UserPermission
- UserPermission::ProposalSerializer
- PresentationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
- Presentation < Proposal
- Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base

What I'm expecting to happen, is that when I call `UserPermission.serialized_for` with a `Presentation`, that `name.constantize` tries to give me a `::UserPermission::PresentationSerializer` and then throw a NameError because the class doesn't exist.

What I'm getting instead is `::PresentationSerializer`, which is no good - used for a different purpose.

Here is what I came up with for replicating the issue in `irb`:
(maybe the above context is an overly complicated explanation of this):

```
class NameSpace; end
class NameSpace::Klass; end
class Klass; end
class SubKlass < Klass; end
Object.const_get "::NameSpace::SubKlass"
=> SubKlass
Object.const_get("::NameSpace").const_get("SubKlass")
=> SubKlass
eval("NameSpace::SubKlass")
(eval):1: warning: toplevel constant SubKlass referenced by NameSpace::SubKlass
=> SubKlass
```

Is there a way I can constantize `"::NameSpace::SubKlass"` such that I get a NameError due to `NameSpace::SubKlass` not existing?

P.S.: I hope the context helps.

---

Edit: found another problem:

```
UserPermission::Template < UserPermission::Proposal
UserPermission::Template.superclass
=> Proposal
```

should be `UserPermission::Proposal`

```
UserPermission::Proposal
(pry):9: warning: toplevel constant Proposal referenced by UserPermission::Proposal
=> Proposal
```

`UserPermission::Proposal` is a class. So... this is a big problem. o.o

I'm using Ruby 2.1.0

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2361347/335847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not define your classes and modules the short-hand way. You run into scoping issues.

```
module UserPermission
  class Proposal
  end  
end  

module UserPermission
  class Template < Proposal
  end  
end

UserPermission::Template.superclass
# => UserPermission::Proposal
```