# Ruby how to use method parameter embedded in call to another method other than just puts

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters

In Ruby I want to use an input parameter for REST verb (like 'Post') in a call to Net::HTTP new but I can't work out how to embed the parameter in the statement. I have the param called restVerb which prints fine in `puts "Verb is #{restVerb}"` but not in `request = Net::HTTP::#{restVerb}.new(uri)` - I get `undefined method` request' for Net::HTTP:Class (NoMethodError)` so it clearly doesn't recognise the parameter's value in the statement. I could use a case statement but wanted to make it more generic. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried the above syntax and a few others like `request = Net::HTTP::restVerb.new(uri)` or `request = Net::HTTP::$restVerb.new(uri)` I'm new to Ruby so be gentle with me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.const_get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12479948/3784008) to convert a string to an actual constant:

```rb
klass = Object.const_get("Net::HTTP::#{restVerb}")
=> Net::HTTP::Post

klass.new(uri)
=> #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'd never have figured that out in a million years. Thanks you

Comment: [`const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) isn't restricted to `Object`. You can use `Net::HTTP.const_get(restVerb)` and avoid the string interpolation.